# Javascript Effecting Element adjacent to parent

Tags: javascript, html, parents

Realised an earlier question I asked wasn't really the most clear way of asking it so I am trying to simplify it and add some more details as I think I know what I need to do just don't know how to do it.

I have a multi-level menu - HTML

```
    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">

<button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Menu</button>            
<div class="partial-refreshable-nav-menu partial-refreshable-nav-menu-1 menu-all-pages-container">
<ul id="primary-menu" class="nav-menu" aria-expanded="false">
    <li id="1636" class="menu-item">
        <a href="http://wpthemetestdata.wordpress.com/">Home</a></li>
    <li id="1637" class="menu-item">
        <a href="http://localhost/frytest/blog/">Blog</a></li>
    <li id="1638" class="menu-item">
        <a href="http://localhost/frytest/front-page/">Front Page</a></li>
    <li id="1639" class="menu-item" aria-haspopup="true">
        <a href="http://localhost/frytest/about/">About The Tests</a>
        <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="screen-reader-text">expand child menu</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="1697" class="menu-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/frytest/about/page-image-alignment/">Page Image Alignment</a></li>
            <li id="1698" class="menu-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/frytest/about/page-markup-and-formatting/">Page Markup And Formatting</a></li>
            <li id="1640" class="menu-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/frytest/about/clearing-floats/">Clearing Floats</a></li>
            <li id="1641" class="menu-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/frytest/about/page-with-comments/">Page with comments</a></li>
            <li id="1642" class="menu-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/frytest/about/page-with-comments-disabled/">Page with comments disabled</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="1643" class="menu-item" aria-haspopup="true">
        <a href="http://localhost/frytest/level-1/">Level 1</a>
        <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="screen-reader-text">expand child menu</span>
        </button>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="1644" class="menu-item" aria-haspopup="true">
                <a href="http://localhost/frytest/level-1/level-2/">Level 2</a>
                <button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true">
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">expand child menu</span>
                </button>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li id="1645" class="menu-item">
                    <a href="http://localhost/frytest/level-1/level-2/level-3/">Level 3</a></li>
                    <li id="1699" class="menu-item">
                    <a href="http://localhost/frytest/level-1/level-2/level-3a/">Level 3a</a></li>
                    <li id="1700" class="menu-item">
                    <a href="http://localhost/frytest/level-1/level-2/level-3b/">Level 3b</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="1701" class="menu-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/frytest/level-1/level-2a/">Level 2a</a></li>
            <li id="1702" class="menu-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/frytest/level-1/level-2b/">Level 2b</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="1646" class="menu-item">
        <a href="http://localhost/frytest/lorem-ipsum/">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
    <li id="1703" class="menu-item">
        <a href="http://localhost/frytest/page-a/">Page A</a></li>
    <li id="1704" class="menu-item">
        <a href="http://localhost/frytest/page-b/">Page B</a></li>
</ul>
</div>  
</nav>
```

Each element that has a sub menu attached has a button that acts as a toggle that opens and closes the attached element. I have been trying to program the functionality of the menu and have got to a sticking point. When a dropdown toggle is clicked this javascript is run:

```
container.find( '.dropdown-toggle' ).click( 
     function( e ){

    var _this = $( this );
    e.preventDefault();


    $('.dropdown-toggle.toggle-on').toggleClass('toggle-on');
    $('.sub-menu.toggled-on').toggleClass('toggled-on');

    _this.parents('.sub-menu').toggleClass('toggled-on');
    //This is the line that doesnt run
    _this.parents('.dropdown-toggle').toggleClass('toggle-on');

    //toggles the chevron clicked to go on
    _this.toggleClass( 'toggle-on' );
    _this.next( '.children, .sub-menu' ).toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
    //Below has no effect of expansion
    _this.attr( 'aria-expanded', _this.attr( 'aria-expanded' ) === 'false' ? 'true' : 'false' ); 

    _this.html( _this.html() === screenReaderText.expand ? screenReaderText.collapse : screenReaderText.expand );
    } 
    );
```

The line that isn't working is the

```
 _this.parents(".dropdown-toggle").toggleClass("toggle-on")
```

The line above it does work but this one doesn't. I assume it's because that while the button is hierarchically above the button that is clicked it doesn't count as a parent as it is on the same level as the `<ul>` tag which does get selected on the above line.

How would I go about toggling the class for all the buttons directly above the one clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to go up 2 times and then go down 1 time with a button selector.

I suppose it could look like this:

`_this.parent().parent().children('button')`

Comment: Hi Axelduch, thanks for this. I have implemented it and tested it and it definitely works for the menu directly above the button clicked but not for any menus higher up. Theoretically a menu option could have many drop down levels and I am would like this to effect all of the parent levels. I used your code but adapted it to use the parents method searching for a list item then searching for children of that with the button tag. eg    _this.parents('li').children('button').addClass('toggle-on');